# Disable FN/language and Lock buttons on Mac OSX

Tags: macos

How can I disable on the Apple Magic Keyboard the :

- lock button (above the Delete) : i press it accidentally sometimes and the computer instantly locks
- the FN button's Input source switch functionality (has a globe icon)

Thanks !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Disabling the lock key

I'm not certain that this is possible, but there are two potential approaches you can try pursuing to achieve this.

### Karabiner-Elements

The preferred approach would be to use [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) to rebind that key. You'll need to use the Event Viewer utility in Karabiner to determine the key name.

### Possible alternative

A possible alternative approach that may or may not work at all would be to see if the solution in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/323266/321020) could work here. I do not have high hopes for it to work in this case, but there's a slim chance that it could work.

Note that this alternative would have the (possibly undesirable) side effect of disabling the "Lock Screen" keyboard shortcut.

## Disabling the function key input source switching

### On macOS 11+ (Big Sur or later)

Open System Preferences and navigate to the Keyboard settings (System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard). There should be an option "to change input sources by using the Fn key or the Globe key", which should currently be enabled. Disable this option.

### Prior to macOS 11

Based on Apple's documentation alone, it's unclear if the option described above is available on macOS versions prior to macOS 11 (Big Sur).

#### References

- https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/mac-help/mchlp2214/10.15/mac/10.15
- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/type-language-mac-input-sources-mchlp1406/mac

Comment: Using Karabiner-Elements did it for me. On my macbook, the lock key is marked as "Lock key on Magic Keyboard without Touch ID"

Answer (score 9):

Notice "globe" sign in:
`System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard` - this is your "double fn".

[image]

Comment: "Show Emoji & Symbols" is one of the great things I've ever found on StackExchange by accident, thank you!